# Ruby Object#send vs. negated equal

Tags: ruby, syntax, ruby-1.8

Why does `"A".send('!='.to_sym, "B")` raises a NoMethodError in Ruby 1.8.7 while `"A" != "B"`does not - and how would the correct syntax for `Object.send` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!=` isn't a method in ruby 1.8 It's hardwired to be the negation of calling ==

Comment: Any idea where != is defined in 1.9? I can't find it neither in Object nor in String...

Comment: @user1196609 You probably missed it because it was written in C, not Ruby. It's in [object.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/6d6b4569fc153149ce648268e4d1df00f7dfa1bc/object.c#L151-156) and defined via `rb_define_method(rb_cBasicObject, "!=", rb_obj_not_equal, 1);`

Comment: @Bryan: This depends entirely on the Ruby implementation. In [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/), it's written in Ruby and lives in [kernel/bootstrap/basicobject.rb](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/basicobject.rb#L20-22) and looks like this: `def !=(other) self == other ? false : true end`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the second half of the question hasn't been answered yet:

```
'A'.send(:==, 'B').send(:!) # Ruby 1.9

!'A'.send(:==, 'B')         # Ruby 1.8
```